# How to fill a property of an object with the result of an async request in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch, es6-promise

I have an object called **config** that I export it in a ts file. I need to fill **config.userServiceUrl** with the result of an async request. 
myconfig.ts:

```
export const config = {
   userServiceUrl: "shouldBeResultOfGetAsync",
   someProperty: "someValue"
}
```

I have a function named GetAsync

```
  export async function GetAsync(url: string) {
  let response = await fetch(url, {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
     body: JSON.stringify(data) 
  });
  let json = await response.json();
  return json;
 }
```

If I initialize config.userServiceUrl with some dummy value e.g empty string, later I can set that property using .then() method like this:

```
GetAsync(myUrl).then((result) => { config.userServiceUrl = result; } )
```

But I need to initialize the userServiceUrl property with the result of async request.

I can access the result of GetAsync method using await keyword. But I couldn't set like this:

```
export const config = {
       userServiceUrl: await GetAsync(myUrl),
       someProperty: "someValue"
    }
```

I couldn't comprehend async programming in JS yet, I hope I was able to explain. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You just can't access the result of an asynchronous call synchronously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I understand what I can't do, but I'm not sure how to set that property appropriately.

Comment: Right. That's why I pointed you to an question with answers showing how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) already mentioned this doesn't work (You just can't access the result of an asynchronous call synchronously: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)).
You should probably initialize it with a dummy value and then set the attribute using another function.